# Is there an equation to find the lengths of the diagonals of a regular heptagon, given the length of one side?

Tags: geometry, functions

I've decided to build an object out of building material with straight sides.  I have 7 units of the building material, to be arranged on a flat surface, and they are all of the same length.  I intend to organize them in a heptagon, which is easy enough when it doesn't need to be a regular heptagon, as I can just connect the end of one to the next until I reach the last which is then connected to the free end of the first.  But now that I have a 'ring' of them, and they certainly form a heptagon, I'm struggling to find a way to make sure the heptagon is a regular one, other than just 'eye-balling it".  My intuition, and my limited recollection of high-school geometry from a couple decades or so ago, tells me that using the length of the diagonals as guides would serve this purpose perfectly.  Unfortunately I don't recall how to determine that length (if, indeed, I ever knew it for heptagons, specifically).

I understand that, for a heptagon, there are 4 diagonals from any one vertex, 2 pairs of 2 different lengths.  I suspect finding the length of the shorter of the two would be the most useful to my situation, but a way to find either one, or both, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily find the length of the diagonals of the heptagon using simple trigonometry and a calculator.

Let the side length be x, angle between sides is ${\approx}128.56^{\circ}$
Length of shorter diagonal will be $2xsin({128.56\over 2})$

The longer diagonal can also be found similarly. I leave that as a challenge for you to do.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't we can figure one out.

Consider the heptagon to be centered at $O$ and to have regular vertices at $A_1$ to $A_7$.

The angles of any $A_{n-1}$ to $O$ to $A_{n}$ will be $\frac {360^\circ}{7}$.

The $A_i$ are regularly apart and lie on a circle.

There is a theorem that if $A,B,C$ are three points of a circle and $O$ is the center of the circle then $\angle AOB = 2\angle ACB$.

So consider triangle $A_7A_1A_4$ we figure $\angle A_1A_4A_7= \frac 12 \frac {360}{7} = \frac {180}{7}$ and $\angle A_1A_7A_4=\angle A_7A_1A_4= \frac {180 - \frac {180}{7}}2 = \frac 37*180$.

By law of sines, $\frac {A_4A_1}{\sin \frac 37*180} = \frac {A_4A_7}{\sin \frac 37*180} = \frac {A_1A_7}{\sin \frac {180}{7}}$ so if the side of the heptagon is $s = A_1A_7$ then

$A_4A_7 = A_4A_1 = s*\frac {\sin \frac 37*180}{\sin \frac {180}{7}}$